# How to get only single embedded document of an array field in spring data mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to get single field using query. I want to exclude embedded field("necessary") in collection. I'm using springdata and mongodb now.

this is query to get spec without necessary field.

```
@GetMapping("/selectSpec/{spec_id}") // Select Spec without necessary In Inventory by Spec_id
    public Inventory selectSpec(@PathVariable String spec_id){

        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("spec").elemMatch(Criteria.where("_id").is(spec_id)));
        query.fields().exclude("spec.necessary").exclude("category").exclude("name").exclude("inventory_id");
        return mongoOperations.findOne(query, Inventory.class);
    }
```

I expected query return only one which spec_is is same as I request on postman but it doesn't

```
{
    "spec": [
        {
            "spec_id": "5",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "material": "plastic",
            "size": "L"
        },
        {
            "spec_id": "6",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "material": "wood",
            "size": "XL"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect when I request to get spec_id is 5

```
{
    "spec": [
        {
            "spec_id": "5",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "material": "plastic",
            "size": "L"
        }
```

this is my inventory collection.

```
@Document(collection = "inventory")
public class Inventory {
    @Id
    @Field("inventory_id")
    private String inventory_id;
    @Field("name")
    private String name;
    @Field("category")
    private List<String> category;
    @Field("spec")
    private List<Spec> spec;
```

I tried many ways but I'm still strugging with this problem about weak. please guide, Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to use the `$elemMatch` of the _projection_, NOT the _filter_ - this will get you the matching element from the array field `spec`.

Comment: @prasad_. Thank you for your answer. I tried but I couldn't exclude the embedded field("necessary") in spec. I also made a question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68644388/mongodb-spring-aggregation-exclude-is-not-working